# Magento, different shipping address - simplification of process on default magento checkout

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.7

I would like to simplify the first checkout step in the default Magento checkout.

The way it works now, when someone logs in and selects "Ship to Different Address" they are presented with an extra step. This extra step gives the user an option to select "Add New Address" from the drop down, then they are shown fields for entering a new address.

I would like to simplify it like this: When the user clicks "Ship to Different Address" they immediately get the fields for entering the new address without having to select the option from the dropdown.

Is this possible to do? I know it contains Magento functionality but I'm unsure on how to do it.

Comment: And what if they want to use a saved address?

Answer (score 1):

The file that handles the display here is located in:

`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

(path will differ slightly is EE is used)

You will see the address input fields are hidden in a div with `id="shipping-new-address-form"` which has `display:none` in the style.

You can achieve what you need by adjusting this template. (naturally you will make a copy to your site theme folder and not edit the core file ;) )

But what to do if a client wants to use an address from their address book?